# Bold a single word within a sentence with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

Is it possible to bold a single word within a sentence with iTextSharp? I am trying to bold several individual words without having to break the string into individual phrases.

I want to this type of out put

Eg:**REASON(S) FOR CANCELLATION:** See Statutory reason(s) designated by Code No(s) 1 on the reverse side hereof.

My actual output is below

Eg:REASON(S) FOR CANCELLATION: See Statutory reason(s) designated by Code No(s) 1 on the reverse side hereof.

Code

```
    pdftb4 = new PdfPTable(1);
    pdftb4.WidthPercentage = 100;
    width = new float[1];
    width[0] = 0.7F;
    pdftb4.SetWidths(width);

  pdfcel4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("\n REASON(S) FOR CANCELLATION: See Statutoryreason(s) designated by Code No(s) 1 on the reverse side hereof", docBlackFont10));
    pdfcel4.Border = 0;
    pdfcel4.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
    pdftb4.AddCell(pdfcel4);
   objDocument.Add(pdftb4);
```

somebody please help me

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The way to accomplish what you are trying is with `Chunk`s. A simple example is:

```
var normalFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 12);
var boldFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD, 12);

var phrase = new Phrase();
phrase.Add(new Chunk("REASON(S) FOR CANCELLATION:", boldFont));
phrase.Add(new Chunk(" See Statutoryreason(s) designated by Code No(s) 1 on the reverse side hereof", normalFont));
```

Comment: `var boldFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 12, Font.BOLD);` because you want a different style of the same font.

Answer (score 3):

Can also create font like

```
Font verdanaBold = FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 7f, Font.BOLD);
```

Comment: How does that fit into the scope of the OP's code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link [Bolding with Rich Text Values in iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315791/bolding-with-rich-text-values-in-itextsharp) will help?

Not sure if it fits your scenario completely but might get you where you need to go.