# How to bold some text in pdf cell?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string, pdf, itext

i am working with itext shapf for some pdf stuff. i have added a table like this:-

```
     PdfPTable tabler1Top = new PdfPTable(1);
                        tabler1Top.TotalWidth = 450f;
                        tabler1Top.LockedWidth = true;
                        //int[] intTblWidth1 = { 20, 50, 20, 40 };
                        //tabler1Top.SetWidths(intTblWidth1);
                        tabler1Top.SpacingBefore = 20f;
                        tabler1Top.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
                        PdfPCell Order_Nbr = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Order Nbr: " + _orderNumber + "                            Order Status:" + _order_Status + "                       Order Taker: " + _orderTakenBy, bodyFont));
                        //Order_Nbr.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
                        Order_Nbr.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
tabler1Top.AddCell(Order_Nbr);
                        PdfPCell Order_date = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Orderedr: " + _orderDate + "            " + _orderTime + "                    Received: " + _recivedDate + "     " + _recivedTime + "      ***Paper Work Required***", bodyFont));
                        tabler1Top.AddCell(Order_date );
                        doc.Add(tabler1Top);
```

and its showing the output like:-

```
Orderedr: 09-Jan-14 12:00 AM Received: 09-Jan-14 1:22 AM ***Paper Work Required***
```

now i want to bold the headings like **Orderedr:** it should be bold **Received:** like this

i have seen an example  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315791/bolding-with-rich-text-values-in-itextsharp)

i have tried like this :-

```
PdfPCell Order_Nbr = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("<b>Order Nbr: </b>" + _orderNumber + "                            Order Status:" + _order_Status + "                       Order Taker: " + _orderTakenBy));
```

but its showing the output like :-

```
<b>Order Nbr: </b>14MA09A8936 Order Status:AD
Order Taker: sbornstein
```

this example belongs to paragraph but i am working with cell here like   `PdfPCell Order_date = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Orderedr: " +` etc. i have a string in `new new Phrase("Orderedr: "` so is there any way to bold the heading. any suggestion will be appreciated, i will mark you answer if it work for me. thanks in advance happy coding :)

Comment: why -1, is my question is not clear to you, i can explain more tell me which point i have to explore more?

Comment: See this for using chunks inside of phrases to use different fonts: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10213836/231316

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this hint of code will help you.

```
PdfPCell cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase("Orderedr", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 15, Font.UNDERLINE, BaseColor.BLACK)));
```

Comment: ok i have tried this but for Orderedr value i have to add new cell isn't it? is there any way to continainate tow cells?

Comment: I didn't got your question.Can you please elaborate it.?

Answer (score 3):

First you need to make two Phrase one normal and one bold.

```
Phrase p1 = new Phrase("Actividad Económica: ", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 11, Font.NORMAL, new Color(0, 0, 0)));
Phrase p2 = new Phrase(" Actividad ", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 11, Font.BOLD, new Color(0, 0, 0)));
```

then you have to make a Paragraph and add the phrases

```
Paragraph paraDec = new Paragraph();
paraDec.Add(p1);
paraDec.Add(p2);
```

and then you just have to add the paragraph to the cell

```
PdfPCell cPrueba = new PdfPCell(paraDec);
```