# html tags not converting when html to pdf convert using itextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I am trying to create a pdf using iTextSharp and it did it. But it is also printing html tags in the pdf instead of making it as a design around text

```
            Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 10, 25, 10);
            PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
            pdfDoc.Open();
            Paragraph Text = new Paragraph("<b>Hiii</b>");
            pdfDoc.Add(Text);
            pdfWriter.CloseStream = false;
            pdfDoc.Close();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Example.pdf");
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.Write(pdfDoc);
            Response.End();
        }
```

Output of this is Hiii with bold tags the way it is looking in the code , but I want **Hiii**

Comment: Please refer this SO link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213231/bold-a-single-word-within-a-sentence-with-itextsharp/10213836

Comment: Just as the answer pointed to by @Ratheesh shows, use a bold font for content you want bold.. Alternatively use the iText XMLWorker to use XHTML to generate elements for an iText document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You expect iText to parse HTML tags in the text of its layout elements (`Paragraph`, ...) but iText does not do so. To get "**Hiii**" instead of "<b>Hiii</b>" in iText you essentially have two options:

- Explicitly use a bold font for bold text and a normal font for regular text.

  ```
  var phrase = new Phrase();
  phrase.Add(new Chunk("REASON(S) FOR CANCELLATION:", boldFont));
  phrase.Add(new Chunk(" See Statutoryreason(s) designated by Code No(s) 1 on the reverse side hereof", normalFont));
  ```

  This is explained in detail in the answers to [the question @Ratheesh pointed to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10213231/1729265) in a comment. In particular you can get a bold font either by explicitly naming a bold font, e.g.

  ```
  var normalFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 12);
  var boldFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD, 12);
  ```

  Or you can ask iText to find a bold font of a font family; if iText cannot find it, it will use create a poor-man's-bold version of the regular font by drawing a line along the outlines of the font glyphs:

  ```
  Font verdanaBold = FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 7f, Font.BOLD);
  ```
- Use the `XMLWorker` to parse XHTML and generate accordingly styled layout elements from it.

  This also has been explained in many answers on stack overflow, see for example the `CreateSimpleHtmlParagraph` method in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30695921/1729265):

  ```
  private static Phrase CreateSimpleHtmlParagraph(String text)
  {
      var p = new Phrase();
      var mh = new MyElementHandler();
      using (TextReader sr = new StringReader("<html><body><p>" + text + "</p></body></html>"))
      {
          XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(mh, sr);
      }
      foreach (var element in mh.elements)
      {
          foreach (var chunk in element.Chunks)
          {
              p.Add(chunk);
          }
      }
      return p;
  }
  ```

  *(The helper class `MyElementHandler` is shown in the referenced answer.)*